# Probability theory: If $X|Y=p $ is a first success distribution with parameter $p$ and $Y \in U(0,1)$. What's the distribution of X?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I've tried using approximations for expected values  of functions and varaince of function. But it doesn't seem to add up to something I recognize.

I think I'm doing something wrong. Should I maybe not use approximations here? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$$P\left(X=k\right)=\int P\left(X=k\mid Y=y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)\;dy=\int_{0}^{1}P\left(X=k\mid Y=y\right)\;dy=\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks! That worked :)

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer is enough for you then you can consider to accept it.